# vba Expected Array

Tags: string, vba

Anybody have a good solution for recursive replace?
For example, you still end up with commas in this string returned by MsgBox:

```
Dim s As String
s = "32,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,23"

MsgBox Replace(s, ",,", ",")
```

I only want one comma.

Here is code that I developed, but it doesn't compile:

```
Function RecursiveReplace(ByVal StartString As String, ByVal Find As String, ByVal Replace As String) As String

    Dim s As String

    s = Replace(StartString, Find, Replace)
    t = StartString

    Do While s <> t
        t = s
        s = Replace(StartString, Find, Replace)
    Loop

RecursiveReplace = s
End Function
```

The compiler complains about the second line in the function:

```
s = Replace(StartString, Find, Replace)
```

It says Expected Array.

???

Comment: Can you confirm that the error reappears after you save your work, close everything including the host application (Excel or whatever you work with) and reopen again?

Comment: Replace is a function name. Maybe VBA thinks you are trying to call the function as the argument. Try with a different argument name? (Don't use Find/Replace as variable names is what I'm getting at)

Comment: @JacobH is right, overlooked that one. You cannot have a variable named Replace.

Comment: yes!  thanks.  there was also a mistake in my function, but that is the reason for the compile error....

Answer (score 2):

You can use a regular expression. This shows the basic idea:

```
Function CondenseCommas(s As String) As String
    Dim RegEx As Object
    Set RegEx = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
    RegEx.Pattern = ",+"
    CondenseCommas = RegEx.Replace(s, ",")
End Function
```

Tested like:

```
Sub test()
    Dim s As String
    s = "32,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,23"

    MsgBox CondenseCommas(s)
End Sub
```